# Should Area51 questions go here?

Tags: discussion, tags, area-51

Should Area51 questions go here or on discuss.A51.SE? It seems that there are many questions here:

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request

And none have been moved to here. However, there is also a tag here:

[area51](/questions/tagged/area51)

So where should they go? Or should we burn [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on discuss.A51.SE?

Also, my edit saying that A51 questions should be here was rolled back:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/212631/revisions

Comment: Just hover the tag, click info, and see the tag's wiki. It explains everything there for you, also as per [PatrickHofman's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263601/230506) below.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from a [deleted comment from Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76835/#comment187048_76835) on a question about merging two proposals:

> Questions about specific Area 51 proposals are off topic for this site ...

So we know discussions on proposals are off-topic on MSE.

Also, the [area-51](/questions/tagged/area-51) tag wiki says:

> Area 51 has [its own discussion site](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) which acts as its own meta site. If a question is only related to Area 51, then it is better to ask it there.

So what questions on Area 51 are allowed here? If you go through the list of current questions, you mainly see questions regarding the whole process of graduating sites, and how Area51 fits in the whole process. Also questions about the site design, login mechanism, etc. seem to be on-topic here on MSE.

Comment: I wonder if the `discuss.area51` is only just recently being made to be the main asking place for Area51 related, because it's been around for years, yet there are 1.4K area51 questions on MSE with Area51 tag.

Comment: The feature request tag is on A51 since 2011. Seems to be the place to be for a long time already. Indeed, quite confusing now.